# Understanding the use of absolute values in the inequalities $-|\theta| \leq \sin\theta \leq |\theta|$ and $-|\theta| \leq 1-\cos\theta \leq |\theta|$

Tags: trigonometry

Currently, I am reading Thomas's *Calculus*. In the Trigonometry Functions section, it is said that the sine and cosine functions satisfy the following inequalities

> $$-|\theta| \leq \sin\theta \leq |\theta| \qquad\text{and}\qquad -|\theta| \leq 1-\cos\theta \leq |\theta|$$ for any angle $\theta$ measured in radians

I understand how these are established, but one confusion:

> Is the bar "$|\cdot|$" indicating absolute value? Why is the negative sign used before the $|\cdot|$ ?

Best Regards

sabbir

Comment: It is needed to make sure that $\theta$ is positive, so that when you put negative sign next to it, it is surely negative

Comment: can not we simply write −θ≤sinθ≤θ &−θ≤1−cosθ≤θ ?

Comment: In this try putting a negative $\theta$ and it will be clear why we need the absolute sign

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that when we are assuming angle to be negative in our inequality , it is negative and we are assuming it to be positive it is positive only as we know that modulus is always positive

Comment: why can not we simply write −θ≤sinθ≤θ and −θ≤1−cosθ≤θ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the | | is absolute value. Consider that $|x|$ is "$x$ but always positive"; then $-|x|$ is "$x$ but always negative. If you try plugging in, for instance, $\Theta = 0.1$, then sure, the | |'s don't seem that necessary. Try plugging in $\Theta = -0.1$ and you see that, without the | | and -| |, it would be false otherwise!

Comment: Thanks Alex.Let me be clear, So Positive |Θ| means  the angel is above the x- axis (measure in counter clockwise) and -|Θ| means the angel is below the x-axis (measure in clockwise), right?

Comment: why can not we simply write −θ≤sinθ≤θ and −θ≤1−cosθ≤θ ?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, try when θ=-0.1. Now it would read 0.1 ≤ sin(-0.1) ≤ -0.1. Clearly false!

Comment: Thanks Alex.You are right.i understand.−|θ| means the negative of the absolute value of θ.

Comment: So in Trigonometry,Absolute value describes the distance of an angle on xy-plane from initial ray without considering which direction(clock-wise or anti clock wise) it is.The absolute value of a angle is never negative same as number.Right?

Comment: Yes, never negative.

Comment: i understand.Thanks